# LTspice model file for new component

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, model

I would like to add some new components to the LTspice library. I have never done this before.

The online SPICE forum discusses 3rd party component steps. It says I have to download the SPICE model file from the manufacturer's website. I have tried to find the SPICE model file for the FDA69N25 MOSFET from Fairchild, but I can't seem to find the specific data clip.

There is the datasheet and other info regarding the packaging, but I just can't make heads or tails of the other export files. I don't know which should be the SPICE model file.

From what I have seen, if you know what you are doing it is quite easy to import the right component into LTspice, but I don't quite have enough experience with the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the file, its a text file, usually cir/txt/lib extension.
You should see a standard header somewhere in the file (after comments):
It looks like this `.subckt XXX 1 2 4`

XXX should say something like FDA69N25 or FDA69N

I couldn't find the file on their site, I would request it from a manufacturer. If you can't do that you'd have to try and create your own or find a similar transistor that has a spice file.

Here are the instructions for import:
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Comment: The similar FQA62N25C is provided with a [SPICE model](https://www.onsemi.com/download/models/lib/fqa62n25c.lib) on the [manufacturer's site](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/mosfets/FQA62N25C#technical-documentation). I'd use that as a starting point and try to adjust the model to match

Comment: Another reference that's useful for things like transistors is this one:  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

Comment: I got to download the file for the  FQA62N25C (it is similar in design indeed), and changed the paramaters for an LTspice existing diode. I also got to write that file into the library file of LTspice, though the symbol fits the pin specifications written on the site of the manufacturer. From what I have searched online, I can change the symbol by importing a mosfet file from file explorer. I tried to do the same thing for the 1n4007 diode in the SPICE instruction steps video, but after I searched for the respective diode directly into LTspice....

Comment: .....I can see that the diode exists on the local directory (therefore, also on the library file), but when I want to use that diode and select it from the list of components, I get another diode, or at least one with a different name. For example: instead of d 1N4007 I get d 1SS294. Why is that? Is as if the information for the diode exists internally, but there isn't an available component, or perhaps symbol that allows me to use it. I created a symbol for the mosfet when I downloaded its files, so perhaps I have to do the same thing? Do I need to create a new symbol so as to use the diode?

Comment: From what I see, LTspice doesn't allow me to file a symbol for the 1n4007, so I wonder what is there to be done?

Comment: You can use a .OP statement to add the model files or do this: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/ltspice-how-to-add-new-diode.95272/ but use the transistor file instead of the diode file

Comment: What I meant is that I used a mosfet file, not a diode one. I have done the same steps as in the forum stated above, yet I did not get the corresponding component in the list. I will try using the .OP directive, but where exactly should I input it? When I make a new SPICE directive for the component, and instead of .lib or .inc should I use .OP, or should I enter the statement when I open the library file from LTC? Or somewhere else?

Comment: The best thing to do is realize that you are simply generating a netlist file, check the netlist file for syntax. Adding text in the graphical section automatically imports it into the netlist. You can also check errors and then it's more like a programming language